# Can i use any Microsoft GraphAPI version with Dot.Net Framework 3.5?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Problem Statement:
I have to leverage GraphAPI but my server is window 2003 and it has DOt.Net Version 3.5 installed.

Windows Server 2003

Comment: You question isn’t very specific... Apart from that if you’re still using Windows 2003 you are better of disconnecting it from the public internet. You can call any rest service from .NET 3.5 with the webclient, you just can’t use the provided Client library

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Graph SDKs require v4.5 of dotnet framework. If you cannot use that on Windows Server you want to run on, then you will have to call REST API directly using HttpRequest approach.

Examples of this are available here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/contoso-airlines-teams-sample/blob/master/project/Models/GraphService.cs#L47

such as the code below to create a team in a group:

```
await HttpPut($"/groups/{group.Id}/team",
            new Team()
            {
                GuestSettings = new TeamGuestSettings()
                {
                    AllowCreateUpdateChannels = false,
                    AllowDeleteChannels = false
                },
                MemberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings() { },
                MessagingSettings = new TeamMessagingSettings() { },
                FunSettings = new TeamFunSettings() { },
            },
            retries: 3, retryDelay: 10);
        string teamId = group.Id; // always the same
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph is a REST API so you can call it from any machine/framework/language that supports sending HTTP requests. The .NET SDK for Microsoft Graph is useful in many cases, but if you're running into compatibility issues you can just make REST API calls directly to https://graph.microsoft.com.

Comment: Error in Dot.Net Framework 2: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Graph 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Success in Dot.Net Framework 4.5 : PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Graph -Version 1.0.0
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Graph.1.0.0' 
Added package 'Microsoft.Graph.1.0.0' to folder 'D:\App\GraphAPI\ConsoleApplication1\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.Graph.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Graph 1.0.0' to ConsoleApplication1

Comment: But my windows server 2003 r2 does not have Dot.Net Framework 4.5. Highest framework installed in 3.5.

Comment: Got it. Sounds like you're trying to use the Microsoft Graph SDK for .NET. That's a Nuget package published at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/1.15.0 . It looks like the target framework version is 4.5.  That SDK is open source on GitHub at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet .  Can you try getting in touch with the SDK owners directly by filing an issue on that Github repository? If you can't make progress there, you can try making direct HTTP calls to https://graph.microsoft.com without the SDK.

Comment: The Microsoft Graph SDKs require v4.5 of dotnet framework. If you cannot use that then you will have to call REST API directly using HttpRequest approach. Examplese of this are available here: